# Kdbg pid() call in source

Tags: c++, c, kdbg

I have been looking at kdbg source code. I noticed there are a few places where the following source line appears:

```
::kill(pid(), SIGINT);
```

My problem is that I cannot understand where pid() is implemented. From my searches on the web, it doesn't seem to be a system call. Grepping the kdbg source tree did not yield any clues where it is implemented.

I am not that experienced in C++ although I have done many years of C development. This is quite baffling. Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd tmp
git clone git://repo.or.cz/kdbg.git
grep -lrE "pid\(\)" *
>kdbg/gdbdriver.cpp
>kdbg/xsldbgdriver.cpp
>kdbg/dbgdriver.cpp
>kdbg/dbgmainwnd.cpp
grep -C 20 "pid\(\)" kdbg/gdbdriver.cpp
>.... Extra stuff
>void GdbDriver::interruptInferior()
>{
>    ::kill(pid(), SIGINT);
>.... Extra stuff
echo "Ah, it's a class... I bet pid()is a function"^C
echo "After following the inheritance chain, I found..."^C
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess-obsolete.html#pid

It's a `QProcess` member function. This class inherits from a class that inherits from `QProcess`. =)

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful and fast!